# PyQt won't display my answer as a float

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I am trying to make a simple calculator that will take 2 numbers that a user enters and multiplies them together. However, when I set the ans_string as a float the code doesn't work but if I set it as a str it works.

I want to be able to input numbers with decimal places and only display 2 decimal places on the answer.

If I run the code with ans_str I get the following error "AtrributeError: 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'setT'

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QWidget, QApplication

from ui_multform import Ui_CalcWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_CalcWindow):
def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
    self.ui = Ui_CalcWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.mult)

def mult(self, value):
    in_num1 = float(self.ui.lineEdit.text())
    in_num2 = float(self.ui.lineEdit_2.text())
    ans = in_num1 * in_num2
    ans_string = float(ans) # << here ans_string is created
    print (ans_string) # << Where u need to put it
    self.ui.label_2.setText(ans_string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sys
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)    # A new instance of QApplication
  calculator = MainWindow()       # We set the form to be our MainWindow (design)
  calculator.show()               # Show the form
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to convert the float to a string, and apply the formatting that you want to use to display the correct number of decimals.  You can use the [python string formatting mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) to convert the float to a string, and also only display two decimal places.

```
ans_string = '{0:0.2f}'.format(ans)
self.ui.label_2.setText(ans_string)
```